# Lock my iPhone app to a specific language (Localization)

Tags: iphone, ios, localization

I have an Xcode4 project where I have support for several languages (localization files) .. My text and xib files change correct when I change languange on my iPhone ..
My Question is;
Can I make a release to a specific languange, even if I have several localization files?
Force my app to use only one localization?

My idea would be to set a flag in the info.plist file like;
Localization = English (Lock my app to the enligsh language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by deleting localized strings and nib files. I don't think you can lock your app to a particular language (If localization support is there for other language).

Answer (score 0):

If the localized.lproj folders are in the bundle, iOS will use them. The easiest way would be to remove your localized resources folders from the bundle and build the app.

You could probably programmatically set code a workaround in your main.m class file, by stating only to use en.lproj but I can't imagine this will be either pretty or useful.

Side note: You can set your default project localisation in the Target > Info pane. Look for key: Localization native development region